# How can I get Google spreadsheets file Id by using Google drive API v3?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, spreadsheet

I upload a ContactList.csv file to my google drive. When I click to open the CSV file, it will create and open a "ContactList" google spreadsheets file. After I do some edit to it, I need to search this google spreadsheets file to download it as CSV.

What's the `mimeTpye` should I put in? I tried to use `'text/csv'`, but it will find the original CSV file, not the google spreadsheets one. Thus I don't know how to get the google spreadsheets file id.
Can anyone tell me how to do?

```
 FileList result= null;
        try {
            result= driveService.files().list()
                    .setSpaces("drive")
                    .setQ(" name contains 'ContactList' and mimeType = 'text/csv' ")

                    .setOrderBy("modifiedTime desc")
                    .execute();

            System.out.println("searchFile ID:"+result.getFiles().get(0).getId());


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, for looking for Google Spreadsheets your MimeType should be `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. Reference to all Google MimeTypes [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types).

Sample code of how to make this request (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#search_for_specific_files_or_folders_on_the_current_users_my_drive)):

```js
  FileList result = driveService.files().list()
      .setQ("name contains 'ContactList' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'")
      .setOrderBy("modifiedTime desc")
      .setSpaces("drive")
      .setPageToken(pageToken)
      .execute();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it and get error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0". It seems that it get nothing :(

Comment: Hi ! I have added a code snippet to my answer. Could you try running it as I have written (i.e first setting the query and then the spaces) and let me know if you still get the same error? Also, in which line of code is this error located?